# Does the topology of Hasse diagrams describe posets uniquely (i.e. what about equality)?

Tags: order-theory

Consider the set $S=\{a, b, c\}$. Now consider the following two [partial orderings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set):

\begin{matrix}
\require{color}
\def\hlcheck{\colorbox{yellow}{$\checkmark$}}
\leq_1  &a          &b          &c          \\
a       &\checkmark &\hlcheck   &\checkmark \\
b       &\hlcheck   &\checkmark &\checkmark \\
c       &\times     &\times     &\checkmark \\
\end{matrix}

\begin{matrix}
\require{color}
\def\hltimes{\colorbox{yellow}{$\times$}}
\leq_2  &a          &b          &c          \\
a       &\checkmark &\hltimes   &\checkmark \\
b       &\hltimes   &\checkmark &\checkmark \\
c       &\times     &\times     &\checkmark \\
\end{matrix}

Note that the difference between $\leq_1$ and $\leq_2$ is that in the former, $a=b$, while in the latter $a$ and $b$ are not ordered with respect to each other.

It seems to me that the following Hasse diagram represents both the partially ordered sets $\{S, \leq_1\}$ and $\{S, \leq_2\}$. Is this true? If so, is there any standard way to differentiate between both partial orderings?

```
c
|\
a b
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't true.
The difference is that in $\leq_1$, you have $a=b$ because of anti-symmetry (so $a$ and $b$ are only one element).

Comment: I see, so if there $a = b$ but they $a$ and $b$ are distinct elements, then we are not describing a partially ordered set, since anti-symmetry is broken, right?

Comment: @AndresRiofrio Right. That would be a quasi-ordering, aka [pre-ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder)